# One load balancer serves multi ecs container within one ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Suppose I have one EC2 instance called **ec2_test** and 2 ECS container **ecs_service_1** and **ecs_service_2** running on it:

```
ec2_test:35500 -------> ecs_service_1:3000
ec2_test:35600 -------> ecs_service_2:3000
```

I want config in one ALB as following:

```
domain1.example.com   ----->  ECS_service_1
domain2.example.com   ----->  ECS_service_2
```

I know can config ALB to route traffic to a specific EC2 instance (**ec2_test**) but I dont know how to config traffic routed to a specific ECS container.

Answer (score 0):

I knew.

Load Balancer + Target Group can only point to ec2 instance but not specific docker container in it.

So If I have 2 different services, I have not put them in one target_group.
I must use 2 target_groups to point specific domain to specific ecs_service container:

```
domain1.example.com --> load_balancer_1 --> target_group_1 
   --> target_1 (EC2 instance):35500 --> ecs_service_1:3000

domain2.example.com --> load_balancer_1 --> target_group_2 
   --> target_1 (EC2 instance):35600 --> ecs_service_2:3000
```